# How to display rows that contain data present in several columns (Excel and/or Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: excel, date, duplicates, matching, stock

I've been searching for a solution to my problem for days and haven't had any luck. Maybe I simply can't manage to search for the right wording for this problem but hopefully somebody will understand me here.

I'm having difficulties displaying data that is present in several columns at the same time, in my case the data to be displayed are trading days for various stocks. As the trading days vary between stocks I would like to have a column that displays the dates present in all other columns to only see trading days in common for all stocks.

I apologize if I'm unclear as this is my first question here. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's the google spreadsheet link so you can see what I mean by different amount of trading days. The idea is to have column A display dates which are present in columns B,F,J,N,R,V at the same time but not show the other ones.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19GsIAtEdWPGcBfNOPaeqNVB7QQNO-bOyg-dCZzDaGkQ/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT: To show the desired output I'm looking for, here's another example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jrIqaEzDPWcW4hkF2YdHq9XYIWjG8PhrewYrBHqEdVY/edit?usp=sharing

The dates are automatically pulled from google finance. As the various exchanges are open on different dates, each stock has a varying amount of open days in columns B-E.

What I'm trying to do is have a formula in Column A that checks all the other columns and returns the data (in this case the date) that appears in every other column, discarding the data that doesn't appear in all other columns. For example 3/9/2013 appears in all columns B-E therefore it is shown, however 12/09/2013 doesn't appear in column B therefore it isn't shown.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your dates are in european (UK) style, ie: 31/12/2014 but your spreadsheet is saved as US standard. This will cause some dates to be stored as text, as they are considered invalid. Ti will also couse unexpected results if you try to do any calculations or comparisons using your data. 
   Go to `File` -> `Spreadsheet settings` and under `locale` choose correct country. 
   Then select all date columns, and click `format`->`number`->`date` or click the `123v` button on tool bar, and choose date.
2. to simplify your problem:

   - for a value to be repeated across all 6 columns, that value must appear in column B.
   - you therefore want column A to contain the value of the adjacent cell in column B, if that value also appears anywhere in column F,J,N,R and V.
   - to check if value of B4 appears in column F you can use [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) function. If the result if >0, than value of B4 appears in column F. Repeat for all columns and combine to achieve the following formula (to go in cell A4) :

   `=if(countif(F:F,B4)*countif(J:J,B4)*countif(N:N,B4)*countif(R:R,B4)*countif(V:V,B4),B4,)`

   - now copy this formula down, and only dates that appear in all columns will be displayed in column A.

Answer (score 1):

Use IF and COUNTIF.  I think this is what you are looking for.

```
IF(COUNTIF(B4:V4,B4)=6,B4,NA())
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answering! however this solution doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. If you look at the dates for the last stock "chfusd" you can see the dates don't match with all the previous "Date" columns. And what I'm looking for is a way to compare all of the Date columns between each other, not only compared to the first as your solution suggests. I had similar results with vlookup and the same problem happens.

Comment: I don't understand.  On line 33 in your spreadsheet, you have 14/10/2013 and 11/10/2013.  Why is the common trading day 15/10/2013?

Comment: I updated my question and added another spreadsheet with the desired outcome! I don't know if this is possible at all to do...